# Enable CORS in Wordpress environment

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site based on Wordpress where I use WPML for translation. `domain1` is my base domain - and then I point my `domain2` DNS to `domain1` where its parked. In WPML I set it to listen to `domain2` for my second language.

Problem? It wont load my custom fonts for the second domain.

> Error: Font from origin 'http://domain1' has been blocked from loading
>   by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://domain2' is therefore not allowed access.

I have tried to enable CORS via my *.htaccess* with:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

And I tried to add it via php with:

```
<?php /** @package WordPress @subpackage Default_Theme  **/
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
?>
```

Nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which file did you added the header call?

Comment: By the way this is not how you enable CORS in htaccess - htaccess use apache functions, you can't use php functions inside it. The right way to do it through htaccess is to add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: Headers are best sent out from the server itself. So if you are using apache you'd need to tell apache to send that header ideally.

http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html